# Change ImageView dynamically from IndoorAtlas

Tags: android

I have this following code :

```
public void futureResult()
{
    FutureResult<FloorPlan> result = mIndoorAtlas.fetchFloorPlan(mFloorPlanId);
    result.setCallback(new ResultCallback<FloorPlan>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final FloorPlan result) {
            mFloorplan = result;
            loadFloorPlanImage(result);
        }
```

And this :

```
public void loadFloorPlanImage(FloorPlan floorPlan) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = createBitmapOptions(floorPlan);
    final FutureResult<Bitmap> result = mIndoorAtlas.fetchFloorPlanImage(floorPlan, options);
   result.setCallback(new ResultCallback<Bitmap>() {
       @Override
       public void onResult(final Bitmap result) {
          //updateImageViewInUIThread(result)   <-------this is where im getting confused
       }
```

I have problem with set image in imageview with an instance of indooratlas.

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Can you explain *what* the problem is that you have with `setimage` in `imageview`?

Comment: im using indooratlas sdk. What i want is load floorplan image directly from indooratlas server and show it into my UI. What im getting confused is in 'updateimageinuithread'

Comment: Have you implemented a method called `updateImageViewInUIThread`? We are about to evaluate the IndoorAtlas product and I'm curious if you got this working, as well as your thoughts on the SDK's ease of use / integration with our own POI data points (office / meeting room locations).

Comment: I have already resolved this problem. So what is your real curiosity ?

Answer (score 0):

Again, your question is about generic ImageView use and the source of the image doesn't have much to do with it. Did you check the tutorial I linked in your previous question? It has a section on using ImageViews: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html

Comment: I'm sorry i just a beginner in android stuff. that's why i'm hard to understanding. could you show me code how to load floor plan directly from indooratlas and show it into UI dynamically ? Also show blue dot in current location. My problem is that.